# jQuery function not working on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I saw from W3C example something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zj4r53p3/6/). An action happens on form submit(an alert). However, when I tried with my own function [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctprwnbq/7/), my action doesn't happen (show hidden div). Goal is to show hidden div on form submit using 'GET' request. I am new to javascript/jQuery/ajax, but isn't jQuery supposed make call to server without refreshing page?

not working javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function showDiv(){
        document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

not working html:

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 

    <div id="showMe" style="display: none;">
    <p>hey this should be hidden</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of the `submit` event handler. Or `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: thank you, the `event.preventDefault()` displayed the hidden text upon button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cancel the form submit](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) before executing your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        // At this point you'll want to have some type of flag to indicate whether you
        // should allow the form submission to continue, or cancel the event. For example,
        // it could be whether not showMe is visible (I don't know what you're going for).

        e.preventDefault();
        $("#showMe").css("display", "block");

        // Submit form after your code runs (or whenever you want)
        $("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("form").submit();` would call same jq submit handler recursively. You probably want to call native DOM method  `this.submit();` with some kind of delay to let enough time for the div to be displayed

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. If I could take it a little bit further: The page refreshes with 'search results' but because page refreshed, the div is set back to `display: none;`. I thought one of the main points of using jQuery/ajax is to send requests to server without reloading page. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you're using jQuery & AJAX, you don't want to submit the form - that performs a PostBack. You should be using the .ajax() function in jQuery to do an AJAX post - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @JamesHill thank you I will dig further into this. At least I now know what to look for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the submit
        document.getElementById("showMe").style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

Actually the `jfiddle` you posted is not blocking the `form`, it shows you an alert that block all js execution (browser behavior), if you select ok in the `alert`, the `form` goes through

the `event.preventDefault()` statement means: don't process anything outside this function

Comment: thank you for clarification on `event.preventDefault()`. I do want the form to go through, but I also would like an action to be triggered. The alert example is just one i pulled from w3c. However the page refreshes. Shouldn't it refresh without loading page?

Comment: if you want to not refresh your page you should implement an ```AJAX``` request (available with jquery)

Comment: Thank you, i will look into this further. I at least now know the name of what I should be looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#showMe").show();
});
```

Comment: should i be using the `#showMe` as an `id="showMe` in the `<div>`?

Comment: yeah, you're gonna want to use the id on whatever you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one form element (button or input), that has type "submit".
Then jQuery .submit() or .on('submit',..) will definitely work.