# console.log doesn't work inside event submit

Tags: javascript, submit, addeventlistener, console.log

I can't do a console.log. Outside the event listener it works flawless. But when I want to do a console.log within a event listener (form submit) nothing appears in the console.

```
<form id="formMovies">
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <button type="submit" id="boton">Guardar</button>
</form>

<script>
var _form = document.querySelector("#formMovies");
var _title = document.querySelector("#title").value;

_form.addEventListener('submit', ()=>{
    console.log(_title);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You mean the page is replaced before you can see the log ?

Comment: You read the value before the user sets the value. Second submit buttons refresh so your console is wiped out unless you checked the checkbox to preserve the console on navigation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery function not working on Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142359/jquery-function-not-working-on-form-submit) (same principle but this is a jquery version)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is when the code runs before clicking the button, there is no value set to `_title`. Take the value inside the event handler function. You can also use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the submission of the form and you can see the output.

```html
<form id="formMovies">
    <input type="text" id="title">
    <button type="submit" id="boton">Guardar</button>
</form>

<script>
var _form = document.querySelector("#formMovies");

_form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
  var _title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  console.log(_title);
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That happened because the "submit" action refresh the page what means the browser console will be reloaded and all the logs will be cleared.

If you want to stop this behavior to see your log message you could use `preventDefault()` or `return false;` like:

```
_form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(_title);

     //Or
     //return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to prevent the default action that get's triggerred ( which is replacing/reloading the page with something else ) on `type=submit` , and explicitly submit the form with `form.submit()` maybe after a few seconds depending on your needs;

```
var _form = document.querySelector("#formMovies");
var _title = document.querySelector("#title").value;

_form.addEventListener('submit', evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(_title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After submit, the page is redirecting to same page(in absence of href or action) or different so you are not able to see the console output

As per my knowledge , have found 2 approaches to deal with the issue

1. call **preventDefault** on the event which will stop redirecting and you see console output

code snippet

**index.html**

```
<a class="clear-tasks btn black" href="some url">Clear Tasks</a>
```

**app.js**

```
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear-tasks");
clearBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
});
```

2. **Keep href="#"**

code snippet

**index.html**

```
<a class="clear-tasks btn black" href="#">Clear Tasks</a>
```

**app.js**

```
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear-tasks");
clearBtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    console.log(e);
});
```